# The improper use of a GetX has been detected when using RxList

Tags: flutter, api, listview, flutter-getx

**I have created an observable list and then storing data in the list from the api as below**

```
class FeedsController extends GetxController {
  final Rx<List<Stories>> _stories = Rx<List<Stories>>([]);

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getActiveStories();
  }

  List<Stories> get getStories {
    return _stories.value;
  }

  Future<List<Stories>> getActiveStories() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(storiesURL);
    Map<String, Object> params = {'apikey': apiKey, 'userid': "8"};

    await http.post(url, body: params).then((value) {
      StoriesResponse storiesResponse = storiesResponseFromJson(value.body);
      _stories.value = storiesResponse.stories;
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      debugPrint('Error occurred while fetching stories response: ${error.toString()}');
    });

    return _stories.value;
  }
}
```

**Here is the code for displaying the Stories List**

```
class _ActiveStoriesListState extends State<ActiveStoriesList> {
  List<Story> _currentUserStories = [];

  final FeedsController _feedsController = Get.find();

  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, fetchUserStories);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [ 
        Text('Active Stories',
          style: titleLargeTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: Obx(
              () => ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) =>
                    ActiveStoriesWidget(story: _currentUserStories[index]),
                itemCount: _currentUserStories.length,
              ),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }

  void fetchUserStories() async {
    List<Stories> stories = _feedsController.getStories;
    stories = stories.where((story) => story.userId == '8').toList();
    _currentUserStories = stories[0].story;
    debugPrint('Active Stories Page: ${_currentUserStories.length}');
  }
}
```

**Solutions I have tried is that make only ListView observable (that didn't work), making ListView parent child Observable that also didn't work. I'm unable to understand where I'm missing. Below is the exception**

[Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKL8u.png)

sample json data

```
{ "status": 200, "success": [ { "user_id": "4", "first_name": "Abu", "profileImage": "jayspur.com/RallyApp/public/uploads/userImages/…", "story": [ { "story": "jayspur.com/RallyApp/public/uploads/userStories/…", "addeddate": "2023-02-08 09:58:11" } ] } ] }
```

Comment: can you include the json reponse of the list you wanted to retrieve?

Comment: {
    "status": 200,
    "success": [
        {
            "user_id": "4",
            "first_name": "Abu",
            "profileImage": "https://jayspur.com/RallyApp/public/uploads/userImages/3346_1675338072.jpg",
            "story": [
                {
                    "story": "https://jayspur.com/RallyApp/public/uploads/userStories/55604_1675871891.mp4",
                    "addeddate": "2023-02-08 09:58:11"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are not using any observable list inside your `ListView.builder`.

But before that you should convert your `StatefullWidget` to a `StatelessWidget` because in GetX, we don't need any `StatefullWidget`.

You can try the following code.

Controller

```js
class FeedsController extends GetxController {
  final Rx<List<Stories>> _stories = Rx<List<Stories>>([]);
  List<Stories> currUserstories = [];

  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getActiveStories();
  }

  List<Stories> get getStories {
    return _stories.value;
  }

  Future<List<Stories>> getActiveStories() async {
    isLoading.value = true;
    var url = Uri.parse("storiesURL");
    Map<String, Object> params = {'apikey': apiKey, 'userid': "8"};

    await http.post(url, body: params).then((value) {
      StoriesResponse storiesResponse = storiesResponseFromJson(value.body);
      _stories.value = storiesResponse.stories;
      _stories.value =
          _stories.value.where((story) => story.userId == '8').toList();
      currUserstories = _stories.value[0];
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      debugPrint(
          'Error occurred while fetching stories response: ${error.toString()}');
    });

    isLoading.value = false;
    return _stories.value;
  }
}
```

View file:

```js
class ActiveStoriesList extends StatelessWidget {
  ActiveStoriesList({super.key});

  final FeedsController _feedsController = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Active Stories',
          style: titleLargeTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: Obx(
              () => _feedsController.isLoading.value
                  ? const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                  : ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ActiveStoriesWidget(
                          story: _feedsController.currUserstories[index]),
                      itemCount: _feedsController.currUserstories.length,
                    ),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You might have to tweak the code a bit but the core concept it you should do all your work inside the controller and only fetch the data in view file.

Also, you should only use the lifecycle which controller provides. Eg. `onInit` instead of `initState`.

If this dosen't work, try to modify your controller file such that you get the value in the list as you want in the controller file itself and you the list which was preseneted in controller in your view file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have marked as accepted but due to less number of reputations it may not mark it